# ¿Cómo me puedo saltar el primer elemento de una fila con ngfor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
                <tr class="prime-grid-cell-font">
                    <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngStyle]="{'text-align': behaviorTableService.columnStyle(rowData[col.field])}">
                        <ng-container *ngIf="behaviorTableService.typeColumn(rowData[col.field])" >
                           {{rowData[col.field]}}
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="!behaviorTableService.typeColumn(rowData[col.field])">
                            {{rowData[col.field] | number:'1.0-0'}}
                        </ng-container>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
```

[image: Ejemplo de cuando ocupo slice]

Estuve probando con `slice`, pero como recorro por columna me borra la primera, y yo necesito borrar la primera fila: la cabecera del body.

Comment: Por curiosidad... por qué necesitas saltar el primer elemento? Nos puedes mostrar un ejemplo de los datos que recibes (los que llenan la tabla)?

Comment: ¿Intentaste utilizando una combinación entre el index del ngFor y el ngIf?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute

Comment: porque esa cabecera del body viene de un SP , y no es necesaria mostrar

Comment: la verdad que no,  seria mas o menos la lógica en mi caso?

Comment: [enlace](https://pastebin.com/YZ1hYdBn) ahi esta el json

Comment: @Legna colocó la solución :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres eliminar es el primer registro del array, el slice se lo tienes que aplicar al array de los datos, no al de las columnas.

Aunque no lo has incluido en el código de tu pregunta en tu template debes tener algo similar a esto:

```
<p-table [value]="tuData">
```

Aplicale el slice a este tuData y ya deberia saltarse la primera fila. Usando la pipe de angular te quedaría así:

```
<p-table [value]="tuData | slice:1">
```

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el índice del iterador (`*ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index`) para lograr esto:

```html
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
  <tr class="prime-grid-cell-font">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
    <td *ngIf="i!==0"  [ngStyle]="{'text-align': behaviorTableService.columnStyle(rowData[col.field])}">
      <ng-container *ngIf="behaviorTableService.typeColumn(rowData[col.field])">
        {{rowData[col.field]}}
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="!behaviorTableService.typeColumn(rowData[col.field])">
        {{rowData[col.field] | number:'1.0-0'}}
      </ng-container>
    </td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: [enlace](https://imgur.com/a/94CsBpL) Al ejecutar tu ejemplo sale queda asi @Legna

Comment: La condición sería al revés: `*ngIf="i!==0"`

Comment: Me elimina la primera columna , tal como cuando probé con slice:1

Comment: @PabloLozano gracias por la corrección.

Comment: @Pablobustamante usa lo que te parezca más cómodo!.